# How do you get all Bamboo plans for a specific project using the Bamboo REST API

Tags: rest, api, bamboo

I'm working on writing an automated install tool using C# that will allow a user to:

- First select a Bamboo Project
- After selecting a Bamboo Project, then the Bamboo Plans under that project will appear.

I have tried this -
    http://bamboo_host:8085/rest/api/latest/project/TC621/plans

```
<project expand="plans" key="TC621" name="TruCare 6.2.1">
    <link href="http://bamboo_host.com:8085/rest/api/latest/project/TC621" rel="self"/>
<plans start-index="0" max-result="12" size="12"/>
</project>
```

But it's not giving me the information I need.  The closest I can get is to use this - http://bamboo_host.com:8085/rest/api/latest/project?expand=projects.project.plans.plan

This gives me all project and then all plans.  Is there a way to pass the project name in the URI to only list the plans for this project?

Thanks
Eric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Bamboo REST API documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/bamboo/REST/5.13.0/#d2e1168) you should use *expand* parameter. For example

```
http://localhost:9087/bamboo/rest/api/1.0/project/TC621?expand=plans
http://localhost:9087/bamboo/rest/api/1.0/project/TC621?expand=plans.plan
```

Comment: For those who want JSON output instead of the default XML, send `Accept: application/json` header.